# «Надоесть(,) как сто чертей» — осточертеть. Пунктуация. Словообразование

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, лексика, словообразование, как

В словаре Г. А. Крылова:
[**осточертеть**](http://endic.ru/krylov/Ostochertet-1285.html) — в этом глаголе довольно очевидна одна из его составляющих — корень *черт*, а вот присутствие в нем числительного *сто* не так очевидно. Глагол этот обязан своим происхождением выражению ***надоесть, как сто чертей***.

В словаре Н. М. Шанского, Т. А. Бобровой:
**осточертеть** — искон. Суф.-преф. образование (с помощью *о- — -еть*) на базе фразеологического оборота ***надоесть как сто чертей***.

Как вы считаете, нужна ли запятая перед "как"?
Как называется такое **сложное** словообразование (глагол + счетный оборот = одно слово)?
Есть ли еще глаголы, образованные по такому же принципу?
(Мы вспомнили только один: **остограммиться** — *шутл.* Выпить сто граммов крепкого спиртного напитка (Кузнецов)).

Answer (score 2):

```
  Как вы считаете, нужна ли запятая перед "как"?
```

Думаю, что нужна, это сравнительный оборот - такой же, как в примерах Розенталя: На самом дне, сухом и *желтом, как медь*, лежали огромные плиты глинистого камня (Тургенев); *прямую, как палка,* набережную (Л. Толстой); Старик *заплакал, как дитя*(Никитин); И *обнялись, как братья*, отец и мальчик-сын (Твардовский).

Надоесть, как сто чертей - образное выражение, но среди фразеологизмов я его не встречала. Сам счётный оборот сто чертей - да, слитное сочетание, а "надоесть, как сто чертей";"обозлиться, как сто чертей" и ещё что-то сделать, как сто чертей - свободное сочетание со счётным оборотом.

```
    Как называется такое сложное словообразование (глагол + счетный оборот)?
```

остограммиться, осточертеть - видимо, сложно-приставочный. Приставка О + сложение слов СТО ГРАММ, по примеру:

> Сложно-приставочным способом могут образовываться глаголы. Например:
> у-мир-о-твори-ть ← мир□, твори-ть – сложение основ мир-, твори- и
> приставочный способ: у- – словообразовательная приставка.

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/656-213_obrazovanie_novy

А вот глагол зубоскалить образован сложно-суффиксальным способом, который, в общем-то, не характерен для глагольного словообразования. Это так, для сравнения способов сложения - сложение + приставка или + суффикс.

Эти способы сейчас непродуктивны. Поэтому других глаголов со счётным оборотом может и не быть, я что-то во фразеологическом словаре не нашла вообще похожих сочетаний-поговорок  с числительным, поэтому и глаголов от них нет. Может, только окказионализмы, но я тоже не встречала.